# Can I restrict iOS app to specific US state ? e.g - app should be download in NEW YORK state only

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

I am uploading one iOS app to app store. I want to restrict iOS app to one single US state. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to limit the availability of an iOS application to a single state. You can only limit it to entire countries.